# Create an XPS DC in C# with a given filename to be delivered to a printing function

Tags: c#, gdi, xps

I am building a C# application that uses a DLL for print.
The print function receives a printer device context (or 0 for default).
If the Microsoft XPS Document Writer is the default printer, running the print function
with 0, results in a pop-up that ask the user to enter a path and filename.

I wish to give the filename myself (no popup).

I've surfed the net and came up with some information regarding printing XPS without user intervention (fyuan blog posts) but most of it revolved around adding a new printer or using WPF.

I am looking for info on how to create a DC that works with the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
but also to have a DOCINFO (lpszOutput) with the filename already given.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will delete filters in pipeline xml and also related dll's in inf file. But yet, as I did, i guess you will face problem of printing canvas (graphics). I wasn't able to convert / transform this canvas to glyphs to get the contents of it.

If you had further issues, let me know

Kind Regards